# Creating a Spark DataFrame from a single string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to take a hardcoded String and turn it into a 1-row Spark DataFrame (with a single column of type `StringType`) such that:

```
String fizz = "buzz"
```

Would result with a DataFrame whose `.show()` method looks like:

```
+-----+
| fizz|
+-----+
| buzz|
+-----+
```

My best attempt thus far has been:

```
val rawData = List("fizz")
val df = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(rawData)).toDF()

df.show()
```

But I get the following compiler error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.rddToDataFrameHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:155)
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going awry? Also, how do I set `"buzz"` as the row value for the `fizz` column?

---

#### Update:

Trying:

```
sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(rawData).toDF()
```

I get a DF that looks like:

```
+----+
|  _1|
+----+
|buzz|
+----+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(rawData).toDF()
```

In 2.0 you can:

```
import spark.implicits._

rawData.toDF
```

Optionally provide a sequence of names for `toDF`:

```
sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(rawData).toDF("fizz")
```

Comment: Thanks @LostInOverflow (+1) - I think I'm almost there, please see my update. I am getting a single-row DF, with the correct value in it (`"buzz"` string), but the column name is "`_1`"...thoughts?

Comment: Dataframe is like dataset in tabular format with column/title. In the first case, you created dataframe with no column name specified, so it assigns default columns as "_1", "_2".

Comment: How would this work in Java? sparkContext.parallelize takes two additional parameters: numSlices and ClassTag. The 2nd isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the following works:

```
List<String> textList = Collections.singletonList("yourString");
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
Dataset<Row> data = sqlContext
      .createDataset(textList, Encoders.STRING())
      .withColumnRenamed("value", "text");
```