# How to create a simple DataFrame with random values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a very simple DataFrame with for example 3 columns and 3 rows.

I would like to have something like this:

```
+------+---+-----+
|nameID|age| Code|
+------+---+-----+
|2123  | 80| 4553|
|65435 | 10| 5454|
+------+---+-----+
```

How can I create that Dataframe in Scala (is an example).
I have the next program:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object ejemploApp extends App{

  val schema = StructType(List(
      StructField("name", LongType, true),
      StructField("pandas", LongType, true),
      StructField("id", LongType, true)))
}
val outputDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD, schema)
```

First problem:
It is throwing error in the outputDF that cannot resolve symbol schema.

Second problem:
How can I add the random numbers to the DataFrame?

Comment: @cheseaux This is not my idea to create the DataFrame. I would like to create it from cero, not from an String or List.

Comment: What do you mean from zero ?

Comment: @cheseaux I have updated the question, can you check it? Thanks!

Comment: do you have [spark sql dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.2.0) in your project?

Comment: No i don't have, I just import it now and it works :) @RameshMaharjan Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Spark DataFrame from a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963495/creating-a-spark-dataframe-from-a-single-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
val nRows = 10

import scala.util.Random

val df = (1 to nRows)
  .map(_ => (Random.nextLong,Random.nextLong,Random.nextLong))
  .toDF("nameID","age","Code")

+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|              nameID|                 age|                Code|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 5805854653225159387|-1935762756694500432| 1365584391661863428|
| 4308593891267308529|-1117998169834014611|  366909655761037357|
|-6520321841013405169| 7356990033384276746| 8550003986994046206|
| 6170542655098268888| 1233932617279686622| 7981198094124185898|
|-1561157245868690538| 1971758588103543208| 6200768383342183492|
|-8160793384374349276|-6034724682920319632| 6217989507468659178|
| 4650572689743320451| 4798386671229558363|-4267909744532591495|
| 1769492191639599804| 7162442036876679637|-4756245365203453621|
| 6677455911726550485| 8804868511911711123|-1154102864413343257|
|-2910665375162165247|-7992219570728643493|-3903787317589941578|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Of course, the age isn't very realistic, but you can change your random numbers as you wish (i.e. using scalas modulo function and absolute value), you could e.g.

```
val df = (1 to nRows)
  .map(id => (id.toLong,Math.abs(Random.nextLong % 100L),Random.nextLong))
  .toDF("nameID","age","Code")

+------+---+--------------------+
|nameID|age|                Code|
+------+---+--------------------+
|     1| 17| 7143235115334699492|
|     2| 83|-3863778506510275412|
|     3| 31|-3839786144396379186|
|     4| 40| 8057989112338559775|
|     5| 67| 7601061291211506255|
|     6| 71| 7393782421106239325|
|     7| 43|   28349510524075085|
|     8| 50|  539042255545625624|
|     9| 41|-8654000375112432924|
|    10| 82|-1300111870445007499|
+------+---+--------------------+
```

EDIT: make sure you have the implicits imported:

Spark 1.6:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Spark 2:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
```